# Statistical and hierarchical Analyze between 3 Fileds

Tags: python, statistics, bigdata, cluster-analysis, multilabel-classification

I have a dataset (Excel file) includes three fields of District (string) , Land Use (string), and Temperature (numeric). By the way the overall numbers of district and Land Use are limited, while Temperature value are various.

with about thousands of records like a bigdata ...

partially something like below table:

```
| District| Land Use    | Temperature |
|---------|-------------|-------------|
| B       | Desert      | 43.3        |
| A       | Residential | 23.1        |
| C       | Forest      | 14.6        |
| B       | Forest      | 18.3        |
| A       | Wetland     | 15.8        |
| B       | Residential | 25.9        |
| C       | Agricultural| 37.0        |
| A       | Residential | 29.1        |
| B       | Desert      | 44.5        |
| C       | Residential | 31.6        |
| A       | Forest      | 17.4        |
| B       | Residential | 23.2        |
| A       | Forest      | 18.8        |
| C       | Agricultural| 36.7        |
| A       | Residential | 29.2        |
| C       | Forest      | 17.6        |
| A       | Agricultural| 36.9        |
| B       | Desert      | 15.5        |
....
| H       | Residential | 26.9        |
| I       | Agricultural| 27.0        |
| N       | Residential | 22.1        |
| B       | Desert      | 47.5        |
```

Is there any automatic method to cluster entire data set in way that describe statistically each district based on it's own  Land use (mean, median, Std., and etc.)?

i want to get something like this

```
Temperature District A
                  Residential   mean = xxx , Std. = xxx
                  Agricultural  mean = xxx , Std. = xxx
                  Forest        mean = xxx , Std. = xxx
                  Wetland       mean = xxx , Std. = xxx
Temperature District B
                  Residential   mean = xxx , Std. = xxx
                  Agricultural  mean = xxx , Std. = xxx
                  Forest        mean = xxx , Std. = xxx
                  Desert        mean = xxx , Std. = xxx
Temperature District C
                  Residential   mean = xxx , Std. = xxx
                  Agricultural  mean = xxx , Std. = xxx
                  Forest        mean = xxx , Std. = xxx
....
Temperature District N
                  Residential   mean = xxx , Std. = xxx
                  Agricultural  mean = xxx , Std. = xxx
                  Forest        mean = xxx , Std. = xxx
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's not exactly in the format you specified, you can get the mean and std for every district and save it to a dataframe with `groupby()` and `agg()`. `agg()` supports multiple summary functions at once.

```
data = {'District': ['B', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
        'Land Use': ['Desert', 'Residential', 'Forest', 'Forest', 'Wetland', 'Residential', 'Agricultural'],
        'Temperature': [43.3, 23.1, 14.6, 18.3, 15.8, 25.9, 37.0]
       }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df_stats = df.groupby(['District', 'Land Use'])['Temperature'].agg(['mean', 'std'])
```

Output:

```
                       mean   std
District Land Use                
A        Residential   23.1   ...
         Wetland       15.8   ...
B        Desert        43.3   ...
         Forest        18.3   ...
         Residential   25.9   ...
C        Agricultural  37.0   ...
         Forest        14.6   ...
```